# insert into SelectCheckboxMenu images

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there a way to create a selectCheckboxMenu items with image like selectOneMenu's showcase example. I mean an example like below:

Used Primefaces Version is 3.4.1

Here's my code:

xhtml-File:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{autoCompleteBean.selectedPlayer2}" converter="player" panelStyle="width:150px"  
                         effect="fade" var="p" style="width:160px"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{autoCompleteBean.players}" var="player" itemLabel="#{player.name}" itemValue="#{player}"/>  

            <p:column>  
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/barca/#{p.photo}" width="40" height="50"/>  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column>  
                #{p.name} - #{p.number}  
            </p:column>  
        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which component library do you use? Check for an existing component. If you don't use any try primefaces, if you like it.

Comment: @johny I use Primefaces Version is 3.4.1

Comment: @johny: how did you miss the "Primefaces" word, the `<p:selectCheckboxMenu>` tag in code and the `[primefaces]` tag on question?

Comment: @BalusC What do you think about this problem?